# Can't Connect To MySql Which is Installed As Docker Container Inside Vagrant VM

Tags: mysql, docker, vagrant, docker-compose, devops

I try to set up local VPS with vagrant, and got docker installed and setup in this vm.

here is my Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "xenial64"

    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080

    config.vm.provision "docker"

    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "install.sh"

    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=777"]

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.memory = "1024"
        vb.cpus = 2

        vb.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/vagrant", "1"]

    end  
end
```

and after i vagrant up with this file, i ssh into it then install docker-compose
and ran my docker-compose.yml ( [here is my lemp stack source](https://github.com/vidihermes/Docker-LEMP-Stack) ) 
and everything work fine. I tested with index.php i even ran opencart and it works.

But, the problem is this : i can't connect mysql database from mySql WorkBench or SqlYog as usual by using this crendential :

```
SSH Tunnel :
SSH Host Address : 127.0.0.1
Username : vagrant
SSH Port : 2222
Password : vagrant

MySQL :
Mysql Host Address : localhost
Port : 3306
username : root
password : root
```

i tried to change the mySql host address into 172.18.0.2 which is the ip address of mysql container inside docker when do `docker inspect <container id>` and does not work.

and here is my docker-compose.yml :

```
version: "2"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./nginx/log:/var/log/nginx
    volumes_from:
      - fpm
    depends_on:
      - fpm
      - db
    links:
      - db
  fpm:
    build: ./fpm
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./app/public:/var/app/public
      - ./app/storage:/var/app/storage
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=application
    restart: always
```

can someone please help me ? thank you

Comment: Can you post your `docker-compose.yml` ?

Comment: Please check have you exported port number 3306 for mySQL container?

Comment: here is my docker-compose.yml file : https://github.com/vidihermes/Docker-LEMP-Stack/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: how to export port 3306 from MySql Container?

Comment: why there is no one to answer here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i am answering my own question again..
for development purpose seems i don't need to ssh into vagrant,

let's say i have this setting in my docker-compose.yml :

`dl_db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=oemjih
    restart: always`

then i put this line in my vagrantfile

`config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3306, host: 3306`

and from my sqlyog panel i just accessing the db via tcp/ip with `port:3306` as i mapped in as host port in my vagrantfile without ssh :

`MySql Host Address: localhost
username : root
password : root
port : 3306`

and i already put it here : https://github.com/vidihermes/Docker-LEMP-Stack